# ORM: Inheritance vs. Composition and LSP

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, orm

There are quite a lot of question about Inheritance vs. Compositions and quite a lot of good answers on stackoverflow yet. But today I came across a problem when working with my ORM. Actually I'm using DevExpress XPO, but the following simplified sample code uses Entity Framework syntax, because it is less verbose:

```
public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Line1 { get; set; }
}
```

The `Address` entity is used in various other entities, e.g. in a `Person` entity. This is of course working fine.

But I also have a `Company` entity and this one does not need a simple `Address` field, but a collection of `CompanyAddress` entities with additional properties:

```
public class CompanyAddress : Address
{
  public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
  public string Line2 { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
  public Company()
  {
    Addresses = new List<CompanyAddress>();
  }

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual List<CompanyAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

Following the various discussion on stackoverflow, I think a `CompanyAddress` *is an* `Address` and behaves like an `Address`. Therefore using inheritance is a correct approach.
But with this approach it is also possible to assign a `CompanyAddress` to a Person. I think this does not violate the *LSP* (does it?), but it feels wrong.

Using Composition for the `CompanyAddress` is of course an alternative. As another solution I could add a new `AbstractAddress` and inherit `Address` and `CompanyAddress` from this new class.
Although the question looks quite simple, I'm confused which solution to prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with ORMs is that people forget that the business domain is the most important aspect of an application. It should be modeled after the ***business*** and not after how information can be persisted in the data layer.

When you talk with your team or the people that will use your application, how do they model it? How do they use the mentioned information? That's the priority.

The whole purpose of the data layer is to abstract away the complexity involved in persisting data. That can also mean that the entity framework entities just exists in the data layer and you have to do mappings between the business entities <> EF entities within the data layer.

Regarding inheritance, you are technically correct. It's an address. But really, what advantage do you get by that model when using the info? Will the company address be rendered in the same controls as the regular address? Sometimes the application get a better structure by not using the inheritance.

What I'm saying is that you shouldn't stare so much on best practices but more on what gives a model which is easy to maintain (thus giving better code quality).

LSP is a principle about following the contract of the base class, usually just coupled to the behavior of methods. For instance if the base class throws an exception at a certain case, the sub class must do the same as that's what is expected. LSP doesn't apply in your case.

Comment: Thank you, I totally aggree with your comments. I won't use inheritance here.

Regarding my LSP question: Of course the inheritance structure itself is not related to LSP. But I thought about using something like a SetAddress(Address address) method checking if the passed Address is a not a CompanyAddress. I think this violates LSP, because a CompanyAddress is an Address and therefore a method accepting an Address should also accept a CompanyAddress?!

Comment: That's correct. A method accepting a specific type should accept all sub classes of that type.